# Method signature return value "Class of type or subclass class"

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, macos, class

When you have a signature like this:

```
- (UIView *)fooView;
```

You can return any subclass of `UIView` * (e.g `UIScrollView`)

And when you have:

```
- (Class)anyClass;
```

You can return any class (not an instance, the class itself) but is there a way to only allow classes of a certain class or subclass? E.g in psuedo code:

```
- ([UIView class])bazClass;
```

So here it should only be able to return a class `UIView` of any of its subclasses.

Comment: That is what I thought. But I was secretly hoping I was wrong.

Comment: One feature thas Swift has over Obj-C...

Answer (score 2):

As specified by other users, you can't.
If your goal is to instruct other programmers about what to return from a method in your code (overriden or delegate method), you can:

- write in the comment (of course...)
- create a typedef like this

.

```
typedef Class ClassOfKindUIView;

-(ClassOfKindUIView)class
{
    return [super class];
}
```

This won't block anything, but it can be a "talking method", an escamotage, to make the programmers stop and think "what is this??", then cmd-click and read the docs :-)

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a sort of type bound on the return type.

Unfortunately this is not possible in Objective-C, so I'm afraid you're out of luck.